# OSFP anycast route different area

Tags: routing, ospf, anycast

So.. lets pretend i need to advertise a route in anycast to the backbone, obviusly same route that in this case is 192.168.1.111 .

Can be a problem if the routers that advertise that route to the backbone area (area0) is always the same ospf area ?
In this case area and the router should be a stub area

[image: network example]

PS: Every router has different ospf Router ID

Comment: Please note:  Your drawing does not clearly define the area borders. It seems to suggest that the border is on the link between two routers; this would be conceptually wrong for OSPF. In OSPF, the area border is *within* a router, with one (set of) interface(s) belonging to one area, and another (set of) interface(s) belonging to another area - this is how it becomes an AreaBorderRouter (ABR). In your case, are R11/R12/R13 the ABRs? Or is it R2 and R3?

Comment: The ABR are R2 and R3

Answer (score 1):

Do I detect a faint scent of homework here?  That would be off topic for this board.

> Can be a problem if the routers that advertise that route to the backbone area (area0) is always the same ospf area ? In this case area and the router should be a stub area

Quick answer: Probably less so because of R11,R12,R13 belonging to the same area, but there might still be some issues, depending on how you generate the route on R11,R12,R13 (internal route vs external route; there's special rules in OSPF w/regards to stub areas and what goes into them or comes out of them) and possibly how the ABR is set up for summarization.

In this thread at learningnetwork.cisco.com
https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/question/0D53i00000Kt0WaCAJ/stub-area-receiving-normal-routesnetworks , we can find this wonderful illustration by user "amascuba", the best I have found yet (although there's a typo in "ABSR" which should be "ASBR").

[image: OSPF inter area LSA flows, for different types of OSFP areas, by user Amascuba on learningnetwork.cisco.com]

That should get you started to find the answers.